# Rename JS filles every build in React

Tags: reactjs, azure, webpack, caching, babeljs

Does anyone know how to change the names of the build's generated JS files, without using webpack? ex: every time you have a build change the filenames: 'bundle_v1.js', 'chunk_v2.js' (It doesn't necessarily need to be standardized).
Context: every time we publish our project through Azure, whether in development or production environment, we need to ctrl+f5 to clear the cache and show the changes.
I've already tried to add some configs in the config-overrides.js file but I wasn't successful.

Myconfig-overrides.js:

```
const {
  addBabelPlugin,
  override, 
} = require('customize-cra');
const path = require('path');


module.exports = override(
  addBabelPlugin([
    'babel-plugin-root-import',
    {
      rootPathPrefix: '@/',
      rootPathSuffix: 'src',
    },
  ]), 
);
```

Comment: What are you using to build? Create react app? it should already have a hash added on to the built files

Comment: I'm using react-app-rewired build